# Django: how to count the ratings and reviews of a post using django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have a model `course` and i also have a model `review and rating` that allows users rate a particular course. now i want to count all the ratings on each course when i filter. NOTE: in the courses detail view i figured out a way to count the ratings like this `rating_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course, rating__in=["3.0", "4.0", "5.0"]).count()`. This only worked in the detail view because i get the course first using `course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)`.

Now i want to count the rating in course lists view, how can i do this while using filter?

this is how the detail view looks like

```
@login_required
def course_details(request, course_slug):
    user = request.user
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    reviews_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).count()
    rating_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course, rating__in=["3.0", "4.0", "5.0"]).count()
```

this is how the list view look like NOTE: **this is where i want to count all the rating of each course**

```
def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(course_publish_status="published").order_by('?')
```

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    course_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name="courses")
    course_publish_status = models.CharField(max_length=10000, choices=COURSE_PUBLISH_STATUS, default="in_review")
    


class CourseRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="ratings")
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=USER_COURSE_RATING)
    review = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.course.course_title} - {self.rating}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Course Reviews and Ratings"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`Aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) the docs have some pretty good (and quick) examples of how to achieve it.
You're looking to use an `.annotate` with the `Count` object. Judging by your filtering for ratings, you'll also want to use the [`filter=` parameter of the `Count` object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count)
I also highly suggest you look into how to properly use the [`Q()` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

With all that being said, an example to achieve what you're looking for:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(
    course_publish_status="published",
).annotate(
    rating_count=Count(
        'ratings', 
        filter=Q(ratings__rating__in=["3.0", "4.0", "5.0"])
    )
).order_by("?")
```

Keep in mind that I considered you have a `related_name="ratings"` on your `ForeignKey`. For your next questions I strongly suggest sharing the models you're working with as well (or at least the relevant portions of them).

Comment: i have done what you said, tnx for your response, i learnt alot. Now it showing this error `FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'rating' into field. Choices are: assets_license, best_seller, course_all_likes, course_category, course_category_id, course_cost_status, course_creator, course_creator_id, course_description, course_duration_hour, course_duration_min, course_language, course_level, course_likes, course_publish_status, course_tag, course_thumbnail, course_title, coursediscussion, date_created, deadline, digital...`  i have updated the question with my models.py

Comment: Can you share more of the code you're trying to use? That means you're somehow trying to access the field `rating` in your `Course` object most likely.

Comment: i have updated the question with everything in my models.py `class Course` i dont have any field `rating` in `course` i have it in a seperate model which i have included

Comment: I understand you don't have a field called `rating` in your `Course` model - that's why the error is happening. You need to double check the code where this error is being triggered - you might be trying to access the field even though it doesn't exist (hence the error).